# How to replace "everyone" access permission with an service account for mount paths created locally

Tags: windows, active-directory

How to replace everyone permission with an service account which can access the locally created mount paths.. upon trying to add the service account on respective mountpath permissions it is not able to access it from the application.

Looking for how to replace everyone permission with a service account

Comment: You forgot to post the code that isn't working